# Trigger en SQL SERVER 2019 se desactiva

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un Trigger en SQL SERVER 2019 que cada que ocurre una insercion en una tabla A coloca un valor sacado de un campo en otra tabla B en uno de los campos de la tabla A, el problema es que cuando se hace un update a ese valor deja de funcionar el Trigger, dejo aqui el codigo que implemente.

```
ALTER TRIGGER FACTORCAM ON SAFACT
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @FACTOR FLOAT,
@NUMEROD VARCHAR(20)
 
SELECT  @NUMEROD=i.NumeroD
    FROM INSERTED i
    INNER JOIN SAFACT s ON
    i.NumeroD=s.NumeroD;
        
SET @FACTOR = (SELECT Factor FROM SACONF)
BEGIN 
    UPDATE SAFACT 
    SET Factor = @FACTOR
    WHERE NumeroD  = @NUMEROD
END
```

Comment: Eso no es lo mismo que: `ALTER TRIGGER FACTORCAM ON SAFACT AFTER INSERT
AS Update Safact set Factor = (SELECT Factor FROM SACONF) From Safact inner join inserted on Safact.NumeroD = inserted.NumeroD;` Ya que lo único que haces es para las rows que se insertan. Poner siempre el mismo valor extraido de la tabla `Saconf`

Comment: Pero eso de que se desactiva, tendrás que aclararlo mucho mejor.

Comment: La version que uso no permite declarar valores en variable sin declarar sus tipos primero, y es muy extraño porque es una tabla de notas de entrega de productos y cuando se hace una devolucion, la devolucion no guarda el valor de factor en el campo. La devolucion altera un valor en el campo insertado de la nota y crea uno nuevo con la devolucion.

Comment: La lógica que usas es un poco extraña. Tomas un valor no determinante para el Factor y lo aplicas a todas las filas según un valor que no sabemos si es la llave primaria o si pueden haber otras filas con ese valor. Creo que esta pregunta necesita más detalles (estructura de datos y datos de prueba con resultados esperados). Lo que es seguro, es que no necesitas variables.